# Is there a better way to define multiple function definitions when using a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, dynamic-library

The following code listing works just fine - but as I'm still dipping my toes into the C++ waters, I'm wondering if there is a better - more generic - way to define each of the function definitions.

I planning on using dynamic libraries as a sort of plugin system for a game, and am thinking of using something like a std::map<functionName, functionPtr> type of arrangement to keep track of each of the functions available for each plugin. But I don't know a way to implement that with how each of the function definitions is different.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

//
// How could I encapsulate these in a consistent way?
//

typedef bool        (*logfileOpen_type)(const std::string &newFileName);    // logfile_open
typedef void        (*logfileWrite_type)(const std::string &logText);       //logfile_write
typedef void        (*logfileClose_type)();                //logfile_close
typedef std::string (*logfileError_type)();                //logFile_getLastError
typedef bool        (*logfileActive_type)();               //logFile_enabled

int main()
{
    // Load a dynamic plugin.
    auto libHandle = dlopen("./libPluginLogfile.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    assert(libHandle != nullptr);

    if (libHandle != nullptr)
        printf("INFO: Plugin successfully loaded.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: Plugin failed to load.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Get the address of the desired function
    auto openFunction = (logfileOpen_type) dlsym(libHandle, "logFile_open");
    if (openFunction == nullptr)
        printf("Unable to find function [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", "logFile_open", dlerror());

    auto writeFunction = (logfileWrite_type) dlsym(libHandle, "logFile_write");
    if (writeFunction == nullptr)
        printf("Unable to find function [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", "logFile_write", dlerror());

    auto closeFunction = (logfileClose_type) dlsym(libHandle, "logFile_close");
    if (closeFunction == nullptr)
        printf("Unable to find function [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", "logFile_close", dlerror());

    auto getErrorFunction = (logfileError_type) dlsym(libHandle, "logFile_getLastError");
    if (getErrorFunction == nullptr)
        printf("Unable to find function [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", "logFile_getLastError", dlerror());

    auto getEnabledFunction = (logfileActive_type) dlsym(libHandle, "logFile_enabled");
    if (getEnabledFunction == nullptr)
        printf("Unable to find function [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", "logFile_enabled", dlerror());

    openFunction("logfile.log");
    writeFunction("Writing to the logfile.");
    writeFunction(".. and a second line.");
    closeFunction();

    dlclose(libHandle);
    std::cout << "INFO: Plugin Unloaded." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine - but is there a better way?

Comment: This might be a question better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid collisions between **multiple** such dynamic objects that (necessarily) define functions with the same names?

Comment: No - I have file_1.dll and file_2.dll. file_1.dll logs messages to a disk file.  file_2.dll logs messages to a network server.  Both files have exactly the same function names.  Either file_1.dll OR file_2.dll would be loaded depending on the functionality required at the time.

The question is : is there a better way than having to manually recreate the function headers for each function inside the DLL.  It's a lack of knowledge question - I don't know enough about c++ to know if there is something that would make the code cleaner and less verbose.

Comment: If your goal is to have dll1.dll and dll2.dll, each bringing the same function symbols with them, and your application will load one or the other and behave accordingly, I can only comment, not answer, to advise you to look at how Qt does it with `QPluginLoader` class. 1. an interface class in a header the application will `#include`, 2. implement it in one or several DLLs  (several DLLs can implement the same interface), 3. load the DLLs (see [`QPluginLoader::instance`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpluginloader.html#instance)) and use the resulting object pointer normally.

Comment: *Cont'd*: Dlls loaded this way can be very, very complex internally, with many classes inside them (the exe only knows about what is defined in the interface but this is not a limiting factor); they can themselves load plugins based on other interfaces they specifically `#include`. Sadly, the reason why I can only comment on your question is because I have never checked how they made it work. I suggest you wait and see if anyone can give a more precise answer than me; if not, have a look at the source files of Qt (`src/qtbase/src/corelib/plugin/qpluginloader.cpp`) and answer your own question.

Comment: Your function-pointers are of _different types,_ while map (or collections like array, set, vector, etc) is meant to store data of _homogenous type._ For your function-pointers a _struct_ (aka _record)_ would be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, if you just want to index function names to function pointers using a map-like method, you can cast all function pointers to const void*. The caller of the function is responsible for reverting it back to the correct function signature. After all, the caller is obligated to know the true signature of the function by, for example, consulting the documentation.

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't answer the question - all that does it double the work by then needing to cast the void * back to the function definition anyway.


 auto functionItr = functions.find("logfileOpen");



 if (functionItr != functions.end())

 {

  auto functionPtr = (logfileOpen_type)functionItr->second;

  functionPtr("logfile.log");

 }

Comment: @Droid Then I suggest you use enum classes instead of strings to index your functions. Function signatures are type information, and C++ cannot use type information at runtime. Indexing to types can only be implemented at compile time using templates. However, templates cannot handle strings. So you have to use enum + template to get the function.